# Balanced distribution of elements to bins based on index

Tags: element, distribution, bin

I have `n` elements with index `0..(n-1)`. I want to distribute the elements to `m` bins like so:

- I want to fill the bins sequentially
- The size of the bins should be between `⌊number_of_elements / number_of_bins⌋` and `⌈number_of_elements / number_of_bins⌉`. The bigger bins should come first.
- I want to assign the elements based on the index of the element. I can only come up with solutions with various for loops. It should be possible to use only one for loop to assign the elements to a bin and `mod` and `div` and maybe `if`-operators for this.

Example: I have `n=7` elements and and `m=3` bins. The result should be this:

```
Bin 1: 0, 1, 2 
Bin 2: 3, 4
Bin 3: 5, 6
```

Comment: Is this related to programming?

Comment: Don't try to be clever; just compute straightforward things. e.g. you've already computed the two allowed sizes; I bet you can also compute how many bins should be the larger size, and the smallest index that goes into a smaller bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof of concept example in Python.

```py
# Initialize
elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
n = len(elements); # Number of elements
m = 3; # Number of bins
bins = [[] for x in range(m)];

# Precalculate this
elementsPerBinCeil = n / m;
elementsPerBinFloor = n / m - 1;
# This is the bin number above which we have to use elementsPerBinFloor
cutoffNum = n % m;
i = 0; # This is which bin to assign the element to
# Assign all elements to a bin
for element in elements:
    bins[i].append(element);
    # Move to next bin
    if (i < cutoffNum and len(bins[i]) > elementsPerBinCeil):
        i += 1;
    elif (i >= cutoffNum and len(bins[i]) > elementsPerBinFloor):
        i += 1;
```

**Update**: I have several example implementations in Python [here](https://github.com/Shadowen/binSplitter). Check the various branches of the repository if you are interested in different ways to do the same thing.